# Can you explain this solution to find Isource (Thevenin Norton)

Tags: current, thevenin, norton

[image]

I know it is current division method but how is it applied ?

Comment: Isource is 15 amps period. If you mean Isc then you need to show where you have got stuck.

Comment: The solution is right-side of the circuit, it says isc=6A, this is where I got stuck

Comment: With the short in place, can you calculate the voltage across the 8 ohm resistor? Can you do that?

Comment: is it 15*8 = 120 ?

Comment: No it isn't. Try again.

Comment: I have no idea then unfortunately

Comment: What resistance is across the 15 amp current source?

Answer (score 2):

I can see you are struggling and, when this happens, it makes a lot of sense to redraw the circuit: -

[image]

Notice how much simpler it is; just one current source and three resistors. So, to move forward, what resistance (\$R_X\$) connects across the 15 amp current source?

Once you have calculated that resistance you can calculate the voltage across the 8 Ω resistor by multiplying the 15 amps by \$R_X\$.

Once you have that voltage (\$15\cdot R_X\$) you can calculate the current that flows through the short between "a" and "b".

Comment: +1 for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the 12 Ohm resistor in the parallel arm. After this, it's simple.
[image: current division]