# Can you help me understand this equivalent resistance problem?

Tags: resistors, resistance, parallel, series, homework

[image]

It is said that \$R_{th} = 12 \parallel (2+8+10)\$.

Why isn't it \$ 8 \parallel (12+2+10)\$?

Comment: Explain why it should be  8 || (12+2+10)

Comment: `but why is it not 8 || (12+2+10) ?` because the Thevenin resistance **between a and b** is asked. Draw the equivalent circuit between a and b, and you'll see that 12R is right across a and b, and the sum of the other three is in parallel to it.

Comment: [Very much related to this earlier question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/538005/can-you-explain-this-solution-to-find-isource-thevenin-norton). I was pondering whether it should be regarded as a duplicate or a trivial extension that could have been asked within that earlier question.

Comment: You have eliminated a source and you are looking into a and b.

Comment: Your last three posts show very little effort on your part.

Answer (score 3):

There has to be a closed circuit for electrons to flow and constitute a current. Thus, there is the same current through the 2 Ohm, 8 Ohm, and 10 Ohm resistors.
[image: branch]

Comment: \$I_R \ne -I_Y\$ And for Thevenin's, you are just looking at resistance.

Answer (score 1):

As you removed a source, you are looking from the a / b terminals towards the removed source, i.e., looking in the direction of the current flow. So what the current sees is the 12ohm resistor in parallel with the other resistors in series, that is, 12 || (2 + 8 + 10)

Edit: Translated to from pt_BR to en_US.

Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry about the Spanish.  Thank you for providing the translation.